# Cannot fully uninstall font

Tags: windows, windows-10, truetype-fonts

I want to try an [alpha release](https://github.com/googlefonts/robotoslab/tree/master/fonts/static) of the Roboto Slab font to troubleshoot an issue in LibreOffice. No matter what I do I always get a prompt like this for every *.ttf file:

> The 'Roboto Slab Regular' font is already installed. Do you want to replace it?

Since I'm already having issues I want to ensure the old files from any Roboto-like font are totally gone from my system and I can't figure out how to make that happen:

1. I originally installed the fonts with [SkyFonts](https://skyfonts.com/) so I removed it using the app and then uninstalled the app itself.
2. [nexusfont](http://www.xiles.net/) still displayed Roboto so I removed it from that app.
3. The font was still showing up at `C:\Windows\Fonts` so I removed it using Windows explorer.
4. Then I realised that I still had `Roboto*.ttf` files at `C:\Windows\Fonts` that were not visible from explorer so I removed them from an elevated command-prompt; I double-checked with both PowerShell and cmd.

Meanwhile, I've restarted the computer several times.

The font does not seem to be available any more (LibreOffice documents display some fallback font) but, when I want to install the alpha, I still get the *font is already installed* dialogue.

How can I ensure a given font family is complete removed from my system to all effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently hit an unlucky combination of problems:

1. Windows stores font information in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`), something I wasn't aware of. It seems to be a map of font names and file names.
2. Such registry key kept some entries for *Roboto-**. There I learnt that SkyFonts doesn't store font files at `%WINDIR%\Fonts` but in a custom directory tree located at `%APPDATA%\Monotype`. There was the unremovable font.

Thus I removed the registry entries and rebooted the computer. After that I was able to remove the *.ttf files at `%APPDATA%\Monotype\skyfonts-google` and the font was finally gone. However I still got the *The 'Roboto Slab Regular' font is already installed. Do you want to replace it?* prompt (this time with the same font name every time). That's #3:

3. The specific font files I was trying to install seem to have some naming problem and Windows identifies them all as *Roboto Slab Regular*. So I'm only able to install one file at a time. The alpha files are broken and regular font distribution is broken too; that shreds light on the problems I was having on LibreOffice.