# No uninstall button for Google font in Windows' font settings

Tags: windows-10, fonts, uninstall

In Windows' font settings Roboto, Roboto Condensed, and Roboto Slab are listed but no uninstall button is provided.

Based on [a similar Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1362132/cannot-fully-uninstall-font), here's what I've tried to no avail:

- Using FontBase font manager, I uninstalled Roboto fonts.
- I reinstalled SkyFonts (having uninstalled it a while back). Roboto was listed as one of my fonts. I uninstalled Roboto.
- Can't find Roboto fonts in registry or C > Windows > Fonts.
- Can't find Roboto fonts in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts.
- I downloaded the Roboto fonts from Google Font and installed them hoping to overwrite the already installed fonts but rather than overwriting, they duplicated. I uninstalled the duplicates.

I've confirmed that local Roboto font files are being used by Libre Office and my browser, i.e., they exist.

How do I find and uninstall these fonts?

Comment: Same issue - with same font.